# How can I get the parent term in a taxonomy with a hierarchy?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I have a node that is tagged with a taxonomy term which is part of a hierarchy of terms such as "state >> county."

As the user has selected one of the "county" tags, how can I get the name of the parent term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the database yourself, or you can use the API function: `taxonomy_get_parents`

Since you might have several parents, it might be easier to just query the database yourself:

```
$tid = ? // the tid of the county term
$parent_tid = db_result(db_query("SELECT parent FROM {term_hierarchy} WHERE tid = %d;",
  array(':tid' => $tid)
));
$parent_term = taxonomy_get_term($parent_tid);
```

**Update - Why I think the above query is smart in Drupal 6**

Some (kiamlaluno) would argue that it's wrong to use the above argument for `db_query` in Drupal 6

In Drupal 6 You can use db_query in three ways:

```
$query = db_query($sql, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
$query = db_query($sql, array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
$query = db_query($sql, array(':arg1' => $arg1, ':arg2' => $arg2, ':arg3' => $arg3));
```

All of the above will return the same thing, so there are no functional difference using one over the over. Why then you might ask, do I think it's clever to use the last one?

If you look at how Drupal 7 does it you will see:

```
$query = db_query($sql, array(':arg1' => $arg1, ':arg2' => $arg2, ':arg3' => $arg3));
```

Drupal 7 requires the query arguments formatted in a special way. What you can't see in this example is that the SQL needs to be changed as well. Instead of using placeholders like `%d` you need to use place holders like `:arg1`. So while the latter of the 3 Drupal 6 ways of using db_query is the most verbose, it will save you a lot of work, should you need to upgrade your Drupal 6 module to Drupal 7. Which might happen in a year, where you don't remember what you were doing and why.

But at the end of the day, it's just personal preference, as either way will work just fine.

Comment: That sql query is wrong, what table do I select from?

Comment: I found it, it needs to be SELECT parent FROM taxonomy_hierarchy WHERE tid = %d;

Comment: @Arosboro Sorry was a bit to quick, forgot to include the table

Comment: The argument passed to `db_query()` is also wrong.

Comment: @kiamlaluno care to explain?

Comment: The question is for Drupal 6, and you correctly used one of the placeholders used in Drupal 6, but the array passed to the function has the structure expected from Drupal 7; in Drupal 6 it should be `array($tid)`.

Comment: maybe either of you can answer this question.  I have been trying to get the parent id using both methods posted here during the insert $op, but it's returning null unless I'm in the view $op.  I asked the question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6746/why-cant-i-find-the-parent-term-of-a-tag-when-a-node-is-being-inserted

Comment: Actually the table is term_hierarchy my mistake

Comment: @kiamlaluno You are wrong, there are no functional difference using `array($tid)` or `array('tid' => $tid)`. See my updated answer as to why I think it's clever.

Comment: The problem is that Drupal 6 doesn't use ":arg1" placeholders. Here are two examples of call to `db_query()` made from Drupal 6 core modules: `db_query('SELECT * FROM {aggregator_feed} WHERE checked + refresh < %d', time())`, `db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT DISTINCT b.* FROM {blocks} b LEFT JOIN {blocks_roles} r ON b.module = r.module AND b.delta = r.delta WHERE b.theme = '%s' AND b.status = 1 AND (r.rid IN (" . db_placeholders($rids) . ") OR r.rid IS NULL) ORDER BY b.region, b.weight, b.module", 'b', 'bid'), array_merge(array($theme_key), $rids))`.

Comment: There is also the description for the parameter given in the documentation for `db_query()`: "A variable number of arguments which are substituted into the query using printf() syntax. Instead of a variable number of query arguments, you may also pass a single array containing the query arguments."

Answer (score 5):

[taxonomy_get_parents()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/6) returns all the parent terms for the taxonomy term with the ID passed as argument.
The value returned from the function is an array having the following structure:

```
array(
  'term id' => [taxonomy term object]
)
```

The taxonomy term object contains a property for each of the fields contained in the "term_data" table.

The code used from the function is essentially the following one.

```
$result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql('SELECT t.tid, t.* FROM {term_data} t INNER JOIN {term_hierarchy} h ON h.parent = t.tid WHERE h.tid = %d ORDER BY weight, name', 't', 'tid'), $tid);
$parents = array();
while ($parent = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $parents[$parent->$key] = $parent;
}
```

As you see, it doesn't return the parent terms of the parent terms of the one passed as argument. For that you need [taxonomy_get_parents_all()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/6), which executes the following code.

```
  if ($tid) {
    $parents[] = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
    $n = 0;
    while ($parent = taxonomy_get_parents($parents[$n]->tid)) {
      $parents = array_merge($parents, $parent);
      $n++;
    }
  }
```

The function returns all the parent terms in the hierarchy.