# Why can't I find the parent term of a tag when a node is being inserted?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I'm following another question I asked, [How can I get the parent term in a taxonomy with a hierarchy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/how-can-i-get-the-parent-term-in-a-taxonomy-with-a-hierarchy) and I can get the parent term when I am on the view operation, but not when I'm on the insert operation. `var_dump()` shows the `$terms` variable, but `NULL` for `$pterms`. Here is my code being called in `hook_nodeapi('insert')`.

```
  foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
    $terms[] = $term;
  }
  $tid = $terms[0]->tid;
  $parents = taxonomy_get_parents($tid);
  foreach ($parents as $term) {
    $pterms[] = $term;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the term already exists at the time when you run this? What does dpm($terms) tell you? Does it show you complete term objects, or just stub objects with only a few properties set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [taxonomy_get_parents_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/6)?

```
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($tid);
  foreach ($parents as $term) {
    $pterms[] = $term->name;
  }
```

Comment: `taxonomy_get_parents_all()` calls `taxonomy_get_parents()`. In which cases would `taxonomy_get_parents_all()` work, but taxonomy_get_parents()` would not work?

Comment: unless you want to find all the ancestors you don't need taxonomy_get_parents_all(). I suggested this as in the previous question it's mentioned there are several parents.

Comment: I ended up using tokens and the termpath token, but this looks like it would work for getting the exact parent term.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Yourthemename_breadcrumb($variables)
{
  // init
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

    // taxonomy hierarchy
    $hierarchy = array();
    if (arg(0) == 'gallery' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) 
    {
        $tid = (int)arg(2);
        $parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($tid); 
        $parents = array_reverse($parents);
        $breadcrumb = array();
        $breadcrumb[] = l('Gallery', '/');
         foreach( $parents as $k=>$v)
        { 
            $breadcrumb[] = l($v->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $v->tid);;
        }
    }


    // rendering
    if (!empty($breadcrumb))
    {
        $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
        $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb"><ul><li>' . implode("<span>></span><li>", $breadcrumb) . '</li></ul></div>';
        return $output;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. This code might be a solution, but OP is asking **why**. So, some explanation would be a good idea. If your code works, it may solve his problem but he will stay ignorant about how things works. If your code is generally good but some minor issue will cause it to fail in OPs environment, your answer is totally useless. So please add some human explanations, not just code, OK? :)